# Hi I download a human model with "bone roots" but no Armature in Blender, how can I make "bone" to armature?

Tags: rigging, bones

here is my model node:
[image]

I wonder how can I make those bone root to Armature.

Comment: These "bone roots" are *Empty* objects. You can use their position and rotation to create the bones of an armature, either manually or with a script (https://github.com/artellblender/empties_to_bones). To get the correct size of the bone you probably need to use 2 Empties to place the bone's head & tail. It shouldn't be hard to create a script that does this if you are familiar with scripting. But the generated rig is very simple. For animation, I rather would use an animation rig like Rigify, Cloud Rig, Blenrig, etc. These rigs offer IK controls and a lot more to make animation easier.

Comment: @Blunder thank you so much, Im a totally beginner on Blender. And your answer solve all my confusion clearly.